Insert PHP Link in Input Type Text Value
In a form I have an input type text in which I save the address where I have a file.
I'd like to put it in the form of a link so people could click through and read it.
I can get the address to appear in it, but I don't quite show the link well.
So far I've put the following:
<input type="text" class="form-control" 
        name="file" placeholder="Documento" 
        value="<a href='<?php echo $text; ?>'>FACTURA</a>">

And it shows me the text with the tags a href but without being a link.
I've searched several websites and can't find a way to get it right.

Your implementation is wrong! Just use the <a href to display the link why do you even need tt to be the input field? If you need to customize the text displayed for the anchor tag then just create a separate input field for that only. Input tags does not support any other tags it is just for the string value

Everything you put in the value attribute of <input type="text"/> will be treated as a string. You can read about <input type="text"/> here.

It is an edit form and the file address needs to be modifiable there.

If it needs to be editable just let them edit the URL, not a whole html tag. When you later display that url somewhere in your site, your code can wrap it in an a href tag. If you want it to be click able while on the editing page, you'll need to make a separate link tag alongside the input box

OK. Thank you all. I put the readonly field and in the future I will no longer leave the option to modify the route.

// Form code
<input name="filename" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $text; ?>">

// Write below code to the action or form submitted file
<a href="<?php echo $_REQUEST["filename"]; ?>">FACTURA</a>

